# Variable in for loop is undefined?

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, scope, undefined

When Update() is ran I get an error stating that map[x] is undefined at "map[x][y] = rawmap[rawmapcount];" and I'm not sure why?

```
var currentuser;
var map = new Array(63);
for(x = 0;x < 36;x++) {
    map[x] = new Array(35);
}

function Update(login) {
    $.post("server.php",{update:1,login:login},function(data) {
        if(data == 0) {window.location.href = "WEBSITE";}
        else {
            var rawdata = data.split("[BRK]");
            currentuser = rawdata[0];
            var rawmap = rawdata[1].split("|");
            var rawmapcount = -1;
            var x;
            var y;
            for(x = 0;x < 64;x++) {
                for(y = 0;y < 36;y++) {
                    rawmapcount++;
                    map[x][y] = rawmap[rawmapcount];
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

Update(1);
//setInterval(function() {Update(0);},500);
```

Comment: It has something to do with your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're initializing the first 36 positions of `map`, but you're trying to access 64 positions as if they were all initialized.

```
for(x = 0;x < 36;x++) { // <= Note the range!
    map[x] = new Array(35);
}
    . . .
        for(x = 0;x < 64;x++) { // <= Note the range!
            for(y = 0;y < 36;y++) {
                rawmapcount++;
                map[x][y] = rawmap[rawmapcount];
            }
        }
```

Also, your `y` range is 36, not 35. However, that doesn't cause an error because JavaScript will automatically extend the range of an array. In fact, you could initialize each element of `map` with:

```
map[x] = [];
```